# How to change URL of a page on button click and change the Keywords & Description of a page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, meta-tags

I have a `.aspx` page which show items hierarchically(4Levels) depending on selected category(`Level1`). I **want to change the URL on button clic**k of specific Hierarchy say `Level1`, `Level2`, `Level3`, `Level4` and accordingly **change the Keywords & Description** of a page depending on `Clicked` Item of specific `Level`.

Similar to **[this link](https://www.gazelle.com/sell/cell-phone)**

Eg:

- When we click on CellPhones it shows different `keywords` & `description` in meta tag
- When we click on CellPhones->BlackBerry-> it shows its related `keyword` & `description` in meta. And most important is the **URL also changes at every CLICK.**

Please can any one suggest me to do the same in `asp.net.`

**Note:** *I am using Visual Studio 2008 Framework 3.5*

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the History API (part of HTML5 so it works in all modern browsers) - specifically history.pushState().

http://html5doctor.com/history-api/

Example: http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/

Good luck.

Comment: In other words - you are best doing this client side rather than using server-side ASP.NET (to avoid unnecessary postbacks).

Comment: Sorry Jamie Cox! i cant use this...as my application my be used from any old browers too..and the thing i also want to get data from DB using ASP.NET AJAX!with partial postbacks..Have u seen the link i mentioned in post same funcitonality now i have in WORKING BUT not able to change the url according to clicked levels..!

Comment: You need to do 2 things - retrieve the partial HTML using AJAX (which you are doing) and modify the URL. Which essentially is just a bit of extra Javascript to add when your AJAX call succeeds. The only way I know to do this is to manipulate the browser history. If you can't use HTML5 History API directly, use a wrapper API that degrades gracefully to support older browsers e.g. https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: Let me explain! All the page contents are rendered using Update Panel & AJAX and their is no some other file physically present for each LEVEL. I just bring the content from DB and render in to predefined HTML text.

Comment: You need to find a way to invoke some client-side logic, either when the UpdatePanel loads the new content (e.g. check out pageLoad() event handler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx), or when you click the element that triggers the update (e.g. onclientclick). There's many ways to do this but all require you to manipulate the history using client side code.